# Count certain character in a String

Tags: swift, string, count, character

my question is if it is possible in Swift to count how many characters are located in a string.

For example I have the following string:

```
"100,101,305,222"
```

Now I want to know how many commas are in this string? Is it possible to find out in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Filter by the character you want
2. Count them

```
"100,101,305,222"    
    .filter { $0 == "," }
    .count
```

It is [swift](/questions/tagged/swift). Nothing to do with the [swiftui](/questions/tagged/swiftui)